# asp.net coreRole-based Authorization different properties of the role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an authorization problem. I know to use 
"public class MyIdentityUser : IdentityUser" to define my own properties to user.
But what when need 2 kind of users : 
1) Trainer 
2) Customers

Trainers need only Name and Surname and list of own Customers when users needs too :
1) Personal details (Weight, height, age etc)
2) When they can train

its looks like :

```
public class Customer
{
   public string IdUser {get; set;}
   public string Name{get; set;}
   public string Surname{get; set;}
   public int Age {get; set;}
   public int Weight {get; set;}
   public int Height {get; set;}
}
```

and

```
public class Trainer
    {
       public string IdUser {get; set;}
       public string Name{get; set;}
       public string Surname{get; set;}
       public List<Customer> Customers {get; set;}
    }
```

But i dont know how to connect it with

```
public class MyIdentityUser : IdentityUser
```

Looking forward for hearing from you 
Systu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an Object Orianted architecture like this....

```
  public class Person:IdentityUser
        {
            public string IdUser { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Surname { get; set; }
            public string role { get; set; }
        }



public class Customer:Person
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        public int Height { get; set; }

        public string getCustomerName()
        {
            return base.Name;
        }
        public void setCustomerName(string name)
        {
            base.Name = name;
        }
    }


public class Trainer:Person
    {
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: So its dont trouble to EF to create db from OOP architecture ?

Comment: There are 2 popular aproach for Ef like codeFirst and dbFirst. If you use code first, this will not a problem. If you youse DatabaseFirst aproach, you can refactor this class according to your requirements. It is a summary that, there isn't any troubling :D

Comment: @Systu, do you use any freamwork for authorazition like Identity2